# Chaining methods causes data corruption

Tags: c++

I have a class structure that looks bit like this:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar & AddPart(int size, const string & name)
    {
        partitions.insert(pair<string, int>(name,size));
        return *this;
    }
    void PrintParts(ostream & os) const
    {
        map<string, int>::const_iterator it;

        for (it = partitions.begin(); it != partitions.end(); ++it)
        {
            os << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::map<string, int> parts;
}

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo & AddElement(Bar &a)
    {
        elements.push_back(&a);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    vector<Bar *> elements;
};
```

Reason why I return current instance of class is to be able to chain method calling, like this:

```
Foo f();
f.AddElement(Bar().AddPart(10,"abcd").AddPart(5,"xyz").AddPart(20, "jklm"));
```

Problem is, when I call those chained methods and then try to print the data, it is corrupted. Instead of getting getting expected output, which should look like this:

```
abcd 10
xyz 5
jklm 20
```

I get random characters that can't even be displayed.

I tried running it through valgrind, but I got bunch of errors, very similar to this one:

`Invalid read of size 8
==3347==    at 0x4EC6690: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)`

How can I fix this?

Comment: where do you call print parts?

Comment: Should have got a warning about taking a pointer to a temp var.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your instance of `Bar` gets destroyed right after `f.AddElement(Bar().AddPart(10,"abcd").AddPart(5,"xyz").AddPart(20, "jklm"));` But you're saving pointer on it

Comment: So should I just implement `clone()` method in Bar that returns an instance that doesn't get destroyed and store that copy?

Comment: you may just store by value, copying ctor will be generated automatically since you don't have non-copyable fields

Answer (score 2):

Think again what's going to happen when you are putting a pointer to rvalue (`Bar()`) into `elements`:

```
Foo & AddElement(Bar &a)
{
    elements.push_back(&a); // <--- Here you take address of temporary Bar()
    return *this;
}

f.AddElement(Bar().AddPart(10,"abcd").AddPart(5,"xyz").AddPart(20, "jklm"));
```